# Rotate logfiles every 5 mins

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a logfile "mydata.log" that will keep on updating every 1 minute.
Now, I want to rotate this logfile every 5 minutes.
I do not want to write any logging info into this logfile but just want to rotate it at the specified interval.
My code is written in Python2.7.

So far I have used below code but its not working until I write some logging.info('') in it.

```
import logging
import time
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

path = '/usr/data/mydata.log'

def create_timed_rotating_log(path):
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path, when="m", interval=5, backupCount=5)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    
    logger.INFO('')
```

Comment: You want to rotate an empty log?  And does the log file even exist before the `logger.INFO('')` call ?

Comment: No its not an empty logfile. The data is populated every 1minute.
Yes, the logfile is there before INFO call.